# Django: Cannot display object image in DetailView

Tags: python, django

As you see in shot-screens the object image is shown in ListVIew. but I don't have access to this image in DetailView with same url.

List View:

```
  {% for team in teams %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
          <td><img src="{% thumbnail team.logo 30x30 %}" alt=""> {{ team.name }}</td>
          ....
```

[image: List View shot screen]

Detail View:

```
 ...
 <h3 class="page-header"><img src="{% thumbnail team.logo 30x30 %}">{{ team.name }}</h3>
 ...
```

[image: Detail View shot-screen]

Comment: What is the location of team.logo ? It should be in static folder of your project

Comment: it's in media. because each team has it's own logo.

Comment: prefix static like this `<img src="{% static thumbnail`

Comment: You should check the `MEDIA` related values in your settings.

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root