# Image paths in Django view are relative to directory instead of MEDIA_URL

Tags: python, django, url-pattern, imagefield

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days and unable to solve it on my own. I am working on a blog site. The post view is rendered at a **URL** such as this:

```
domain.com/blog/specificpost/
```

I have an **ImageField** in my model. The images upload properly and I can address the images at the correct URLs.

```
domain.com/media/asset.jpg
```

In my **settings.py** I have defined the media paths. When I access the image files from the Admin, they work properly.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When rendering the view of the post, the image path is rendered incorrectly in the DOM. It is:

```
domain.com/blog/media/asset.jpg
```

It should be:

```
domain.com/media/asset.jpg
```

In my **urlpattern** I have appended:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and added the relevant imports to urls.py. I believe this code is supposed to serve the files at the domain root during [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

I have tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root), but the image URLs still render relative to the directory. Any help to set me on the correct path would be useful, thank you very much.

Post template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block journal_entry %}
    <main class="content">
        <section class="photo">
            <img src="{{ object.image }}">
        </section>
        <section class="entry">
            <section class="entry-content">
                {{ object.body|linebreaks }}
            </section>
            <section class="entry-meta">
                {{ object.created }}<span class="user-options"> • <a href="#">Delete</a></span>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you add the template of your view?

Comment: @MrName Added, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `{{ object.image.url }}` instead of `{{ object.image }}` in your template.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Didn't realize that you had to be specific with the output of the ImageField. I knew it was going to be a simple mistake, just couldn't put my head around what I was missing. I appreciate the help, thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, I think what happens when you reference the field itself (instead of the URL attribute) is that it uses the `__str__` method of the class, which is a relative URI, as opposed to the `url` field, which is a full URL.