# Alternative to Django's image.url method?

Tags: python, django, image, inline-formset

I'm using an inlineformset so that a user can upload multiple images at once. The images are saved and functionality is as expected, except on the front-end side. When I loop through my formset with a method resembling {{ form. image }}, I can clearly see that my image is saved and when I click the url, I am redirected to the uploaded file. The problem seems to be that the absoulte url is not stored when I try to set the image's URL as a src for an image element.

Trying to log MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in a `<p>` tag yields no results.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')    
ROOT_URLCONF = 'dashboard_app.urls'
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
app_name = 'Accounts_Namespace'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Register, name='Accounts_Register'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.ChangePassword, name="Accounts_Change_Password"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.Login, name='Accounts_Login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout, name='Accounts_Logout'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.ViewProfile, name='Accounts_View_Profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.EditProfile, name="Accounts_Edit_Profile"),
    url(r'^school/', include('student_map_app.urls', namespace="Student_Maps_Namespace")),

 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery_images")
uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def EditProfile(request):
user = request.user

galleryInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(get_user_model(), Gallery, form=GalleryForm)
selectedUserGallery = Gallery.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('uploaded')
userGallery_initial = [{'image': selection.image} for selection in selectedUserGallery] # Using this syntax because formset initials accept dictionaries

if request.method == "POST":
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    gallery_inlineformset = galleryInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)   # Essentially, we're passing a queryset

    if profile_form.is_valid() and gallery_inlineformset.is_valid():
        # Altering the User model through the UserProfile model's UserProfileForm representative
        user.first_name = profile_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = profile_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()

        new_images = []

        for gallery_form in gallery_inlineformset:
            image = gallery_form.cleaned_data.get('image')
            if image:
                new_images.append(Gallery(user=user, image=image))
        try:
            Gallery.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
            Gallery.objects.bulk_create(new_images)
            messages.success(request, 'You have updated your profile.')
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error saving your profile.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('https://www.youtube.com')

else:
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.user)
    gallery_inlineformset = galleryInlineFormSet(initial=userGallery_initial)

args = { 'profile_form':profile_form, 'gallery_inlineformset':gallery_inlineformset }
return render(request, 'accounts_app/editprofile.html', args)
```

editprofile.html

```
    {% block main %}
<section class="Container">
    <section class="Main-Content">
        <form id="post_form" method="POST" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ gallery_inlineformset.management_form }}
            {% for gallery_form in gallery_inlineformset %}
                <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ gallery_form.image }}    <!-- Show the image upload field -->
                    <p>{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}</p>
                    <p>{{ MEDIA_URL }}</p>
                    <img src="/media/{{gallery_form.image.image.url}}">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </section>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Again, when I try:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ gallery_form.image.url }}">
```

I get a value of "unknown" as the source, but I can click the link that "{{ gallery_form.image}}" generates and see the image that was uploaded. Trying to log both "MEDIA_URL" and "MEDIA_ROOT" yields no results. Not quite sure where the issue lies.

Comment: It seems like this could be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root?rq=1

Comment: @SamHollenbach I've already used that thread (and many others) as a reference. Unfortunately, the reason I'm here is because I couldn't find a solution. Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't figure out why I couldn't use the .url() method Django has predefined, I did however, end up using another solution suggested to me by a user in a previous question of mine. Basically, after a user has uploaded images and we have them stored in a database, we make a variable storing the URL attribute of those images, and access that variable from the template. It looks something like this:

views.py

```
selectedUserGallery = Gallery.objects.filter(user=user) # Get gallery objects where user is request.user
userGallery_initial = [{'image': selection.image, 'image_url':selection.image.url} for selection in selectedUserGallery if selection.image]
if request.method == "GET":
    print("--------GET REQUEST: PRESENTING PRE-EXISTING GALLERY IMAGES.-------")
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.user)
    gallery_inlineformset = galleryInlineFormSet(initial=userGallery_initial)
```

template.html

```
<form id="post_form" method="POST" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ gallery_inlineformset.management_form }}
            {% for gallery_form in gallery_inlineformset %}
                <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ gallery_form.image }}    <!-- Show the image upload field, this is not he image var from views.py -->
                    {% if gallery_form.image is not None %}
                        <p>The image should be below:</p>
                        <img src="{{ gallery_form.initial.image_url }}">
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="gallery-submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Also, I ended up replacing most of code from the original post as I'm no longer using bulk_create().

Answer (score 1):

Use `<img src="{{ gallery_form.image.url }}">` and make sure `image` is not `None`

add this line in your `urls.py`

`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: I just tested and image is not None. Still having the same issue.

Comment: is your `image` in media folder?

Comment: Yes, all images are uploaded to the specified folder. @ShafikurRahmanShaon

Comment: can you please debug what your image `src` get actually?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I just know I get "unknown" for it when I inspect with Chrome.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I don't have deep knowledge about your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I already have urls.py setup. I updated my question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `{{MEDIA_URL}}` before address of your image. because by default it will add `/media` before your image url path.

Also be sure to add all path starting `media` to your urls.

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

also when trying to print an image url in django template, handle situations that image not exist like this:

```
<img src="{% if gallery_form.image %}{{ gallery_form.image.url }}{%else%} <default-image-path-here> {%endif%}"
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I already have the urls.py setup. I've updated my question so you can see it. Still can't get past the issue. Also, thank you for the tip about checking for non-existing images.