# Images are not getting loaded from static file

Tags: django

```js
"""
codes in settings.py
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*-by0qr_kjdy8soie*gt*lg0vo+pc(1#34b5g-q1e=uv5%phzt'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'travello.apps.TravelloConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'telusko.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'telusko.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/images/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

```js
Added bellow code but still it has not solved

MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/images/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

```js
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

I have added bootstrap template to my Django project. I am facing the problem with the images are not getting load when check index.html in local host, when I inspect the html code it's showing error like this "GET /images/destination_4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2300" while All other static files are getting loaded. I have ensured that the presense of 'django.contrib.staticfiles', in installed app, also added STATIC_DIR and STATIC_ROOT in settings.py and in html page static files are loaded. Please let me know the solution. I have added index.html code and STATIC_URL below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Travello</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Travello template project">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/main_styles.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/responsive.css' %}">

</head>
<body>

<div class="super_container">
 
 <!-- Header -->

 <header class="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="header_content d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
      <div class="header_content_inner d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
       <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Travello</a></div>
       <nav class="main_nav">
        <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
         <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
       <div class="header_phone ml-auto">Call us: 00-56 445 678 33</div>

       <!-- Hamburger -->

       <div class="hamburger ml-auto">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header_social d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
   <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>

 <!-- Menu -->

 <div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_header d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
   <div class="menu_logo"><a href="index.html">Travello</a></div>
   <div class="menu_close_container ml-auto"><div class="menu_close"><div></div><div></div></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_content">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="inex.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_social">
   <div class="menu_phone ml-auto">Call us: 00-56 445 678 33</div>
   <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Home -->

 <div class="home">
  
  <!-- Home Slider -->
  <div class="home_slider_container">
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home_slider">
    
    <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="owl-item">
     <div class="background_image" style="background-image:  url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="home_slider_content_container">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="home_slider_content">
          <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="owl-item">
     <div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="home_slider_content_container">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="home_slider_content">
          <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="owl-item">
     <div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="home_slider_content_container">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="home_slider_content">
          <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="home_page_nav">
    <ul class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
     <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#destinations">Offers<span>01</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#testimonials">Testimonials<span>02</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#news">Latest<span>03</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Search -->

 <div class="home_search">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="home_search_container">
      <div class="home_search_title">Search for your trip</div>
      <div class="home_search_content">
       <form action="#" class="home_search_form" id="home_search_form">
        <div class="d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-lg-between justify-content-start">
         <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_1" placeholder="City" required="required">
         <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_2" placeholder="Departure" required="required">
         <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_3" placeholder="Arrival" required="required">
         <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_4" placeholder="Budget" required="required">
         <button class="home_search_button">search</button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Intro -->

 <div class="intro">
  <div class="intro_background" style="background-image:url(images/intro.png)"></div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="intro_container">
      <div class="row">

       <!-- Intro Item -->
       <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
        <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div class="intro_icon"><img src="images/beach.svg" alt=""></div>
         <div class="intro_content">
          <div class="intro_title">Top Destinations</div>
          <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <!-- Intro Item -->
       <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
        <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div class="intro_icon"><img src="images/wallet.svg" alt=""></div>
         <div class="intro_content">
          <div class="intro_title">The Best Prices</div>
          <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Sollicitudin mauris lobortis in.</p></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <!-- Intro Item -->
       <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
        <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div class="intro_icon"><img src="images/suitcase.svg" alt=""></div>
         <div class="intro_content">
          <div class="intro_title">Amazing Services</div>
          <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Destinations -->

 <div class="destinations" id="destinations">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
     <div class="section_subtitle">simply amazing places</div>
     <div class="section_title"><h2>Popular Destinations</h2></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row destinations_row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="destinations_container item_grid">

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">Bali</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_2.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">Indonesia</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_3.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">San Francisco</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_4.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">Paris</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_5.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">Phi Phi Island</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Destination -->
      <div class="destination item">
       <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="images/destination_6.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">Mykonos</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From $679</div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Testimonials -->

 <div class="testimonials" id="testimonials">
  <div class="parallax_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/testimonials.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
     <div class="section_subtitle">simply amazing places</div>
     <div class="section_title"><h2>Testimonials</h2></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row testimonials_row">
    <div class="col">

     <!-- Testimonials Slider -->
     <div class="testimonials_slider_container">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme testimonials_slider">
       
       <!-- Slide -->
       <div class="owl-item text-center">
        <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
        <div class="testimonial_author">
         <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
          <div>john turner,</div>
          <div>client</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <!-- Slide -->
       <div class="owl-item text-center">
        <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
        <div class="testimonial_author">
         <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
          <div>john turner,</div>
          <div>client</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <!-- Slide -->
       <div class="owl-item text-center">
        <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
        <div class="testimonial_author">
         <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
          <div>john turner,</div>
          <div>client</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_nav">
   <ul class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
    <li><a href="#">City Breaks Clients<span>01</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cruises Clients<span>02</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">All Inclusive Clients<span>03</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- News -->

 <div class="news" id="news">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8">
     <div class="news_container">
      
      <!-- News Post -->
      <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
       <div class="news_post_image"><img src="images/news_1.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div class="news_post_content">
        <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div>02</div>
         <div>june</div>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
        <div class="news_post_category">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_text">
         <p>Pellentesque sit amet elementum ccumsan sit amet mattis eget, tristique at leo. Vivamus massa.Tempor massa et laoreet.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- News Post -->
      <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
       <div class="news_post_image"><img src="images/news_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div class="news_post_content">
        <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div>01</div>
         <div>june</div>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
        <div class="news_post_category">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_text">
         <p>Tempor massa et laoreet malesuada. Pellentesque sit amet elementum ccumsan sit amet mattis eget, tristique at leo.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- News Post -->
      <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
       <div class="news_post_image"><img src="images/news_3.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div class="news_post_content">
        <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
         <div>29</div>
         <div>may</div>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
        <div class="news_post_category">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="news_post_text">
         <p>Vivamus massa.Tempor massa et laoreet malesuada. Aliquam nulla nisl, accumsan sit amet mattis.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- News Sidebar -->
    <div class="col-xl-4">
     <div class="travello">
      <div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(images/travello.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="travello_content">
       <div class="travello_content_inner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="travello_container">
       <a href="#">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-end">
         <span class="travello_title">Get a 20% Discount</span>
         <span class="travello_subtitle">Buy Your Vacation Online Now</span>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Footer -->

 <footer class="footer">
  <div class="parallax_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/footer_1.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="newsletter">
      <div class="newsletter_title_container text-center">
       <div class="newsletter_title">Subscribe to our newsletter to get the latest trends & news</div>
       <div class="newsletter_subtitle">Join our database NOW!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsletter_form_container">
       <form action="#" class="newsletter_form d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between" id="newsletter_form">
        <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between">
         <div><input type="text" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_name" id="newsletter_input_name" placeholder="Name" required="required"><div class="input_border"></div></div>
         <div><input type="email" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_email" id="newsletter_input_email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required="required"><div class="input_border"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div><button class="newsletter_button">subscribe</button></div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row footer_contact_row">
    <div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-1">
     <div class="row">

      <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
      <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
       <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
        <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="images/sign.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="footer_contact_title">give us a call</div>
        <div class="footer_contact_list">
         <ul>
          <li>Office Landline: +44 5567 32 664 567</li>
          <li>Mobile: +44 5567 89 3322 332</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
      <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
       <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
        <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="images/trekking.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="footer_contact_title">come & drop by</div>
        <div class="footer_contact_list">
         <ul style="max-width:190px">
          <li>4124 Barnes Street, Sanford, FL 32771</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
      <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
       <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
        <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="images/around.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="footer_contact_title">send us a message</div>
        <div class="footer_contact_list">
         <ul>
          <li>youremail@gmail.com</li>
          <li>Office@yourbusinessname.com</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-center"><!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --> </div>
 </footer>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/Isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/easing/easing.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .background_image {
            background-image: url(images/home_slider.jpg);
        }
    </style>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably URLs of _other_ files start with `/static/`.

Comment: There is only one file named /static/ no such other file are there in this project

Comment: show the template

Comment: show us your STATIC_URL setting and your index.html template where the <img> is. Also look at the other images you mention, what is the url for those?

Comment: Please take look at the above code for reference.

Comment: to load the images set the django media url see this answer and try to understand something:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root

Comment: media url also added but not been solved yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, this log record

> GET /images/destination_4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2300

is clearly saying that you're trying to access URL which is not under `STATIC_URL` address. Since you said that some of files work fine I surmised that config is correct but image URL is not.

Here is an example of well defined static file URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

here all your Django settings for static files will take effect.

Below is one of the problematic places:

```
<img src="images/destination_4.jpg" alt="">
```

`static` template tag is not used here thus this is just a constant URL. Moreover, this is relative URL (because it does not start with `/`) and will result in different absolute URL on different pages. Fix this, start using `static` template tag here and images will load just fine (if they exist in specified folder).

One more thing which is perhaps the cause of other problems:
you defined `MEDIA_ROOT` as `/static/images/media` which is inside `static` files folder. That is not really a good idea. Note, **media** files in Django mean dynamic, editable files uploaded by users. If an image or a video is a part of your solution (like logo, favicon, backround image) - they are not "media" in terms of Django - they are "static" files. Yes, you can put them into separate subfolder just like any `.js` or `.css` files - but they will remain *static* and you have to work with them like with other static files.

You should not mix **media** files with **static** inside one directory because you will be overwriting static folder from time to time during deployment of new releases of your Django project.

Comment: Thank you Ivan Starostin, Problem have solved because of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
Thanks to Ivan Starostin. He suggested to to add static tag to all images, I followed his instruction made changes now the code is working.

Before changes `class="background_image" style="background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>`

After changes `<div class="background_image" style="background-image:  url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %})"></div>`