# django-how to upload image using ImageField in a model form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-media

My form doesn't save the uploaded image in the path given, my code:

**models.py:**

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(SomeClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='static/zzz/xxx/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class edit_profile_form(forms.Form):
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField(label='Avatar',widget=forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control input_data',
                'placeholder': 'Upload',}))
```

**views.py**

```
def validate_edit_profile(request):

   template = loader.get_template('account/edit_.html')
   user_form = edit_profile_form(request.POST,request.FILES) 
   userprofile = EcomCustomerProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)

   #if user submit
   if request.POST:
      if user_form.is_valid():
      # get the data
         first_name = user_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
         last_name = user_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
         phone = user_form.cleaned_data['phone']
         profile_picture = user_form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']

         #change db
         get_user = EcomCustomer.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
         get_user.first_name = first_name
         get_user.last_name = last_name
         get_user.phone = phone
         get_user.profile_picture = profile_picture

         user_form.save()
         get_user.save()
         return HttpResponse(template.render({'userprofile':userprofile}, request))
```

I'm using two forms: one for text, the other for uploading the image.
But it doesn't upload anything.

What's the problem ?

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834540/5921826 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462881/images-are-not-getting-loaded-from-static-file/56466611#56466611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there might be an issue in your views.py where you are trying to save the form data and the user instance. Here are a few suggestions to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Check the form validation:
   Ensure that the form is valid before trying to access its cleaned data. Use `is_valid()` before attempting to access the cleaned data.

   ```py
   if user_form.is_valid():
       # Your code for saving data
   ```
2. **Handling the image upload:**
   In your code, you are trying to save the form data and user instance separately. Instead, you should save the user instance with the associated profile picture.

   ```py
   if user_form.is_valid():
       get_user.first_name = first_name
       get_user.last_name = last_name
       get_user.phone = phone
       get_user.profile_picture = profile_picture
       get_user.save()
   ```
3. ImageField handling in models:
   Ensure that the `upload_to` path is correct and exists in your project structure. The 'static/zzz/xxx/' path should be relative to your MEDIA_ROOT.

   ```py
   profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='zzz/xxx/')
   ```
4. Check the enctype attribute in your HTML form:
   Ensure that your HTML form has the correct `enctype` attribute set for file uploads.

   ```html
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <!-- Your form fields here -->
   </form>
   ```

Make these adjustments, and it should help resolve the issue with the image not being saved.

Comment: I'm not using a media url since my project is on production, is it possible with static files?