# How to save image in django media root storage from python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save my images to the media root folder which I've named pictures in the media folder. This is my code and I want whenever my function is making the screenshot it should save the screenshots in my media root folder.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,render,redirect
import time 
import random
from django.db import models
import pyautogui
import sys
from shots.models import pictures
from .models import pictures
from shots.forms.forms import DocumentForm

def button(request):
    import pyautogui
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    storage=pictures.pictures2
    myScreenshot.save(storage)

    return render(request,'index.html')

def output(request):
    return HttpResponse("""Hello, world. You're at the polls index.
    your Screenshot should start now""")
```

This is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
import random


class pictures(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    pictures2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

Comment: what are your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings?

Answer (score 0):

You will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518073/4243927) helpful.

The files for `FileField` and `ImageField` are uploaded relative to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` and should be accessible by the same relative filename appended to `settings.MEDIA_URL`.

---

That being said, if you named your `settings.MEDIA_ROOT = 'pictures'` and you are telling your models to `upload_to='pictures'` So files uploaded by django will end up in:

```python
**/pictures/pictures/myScreenshot.png**
```

```python
import pyautogui

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings

from .models import pictures


def button(request):
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

    """ 
    The path and filename are relative o where you execute this script.
    """
    filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'pictures/myScreenshot.png'
    myScreenshot.save(filename)

    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Your `models.py`:

```python
from django.db import models
import random


class pictures(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    pictures2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

Comment: i know of that what i what to get is how will i be able to save the files from the screenshot to the root directory

Comment: thank you i tried it but also i can't find the screenshots in my folder...
please is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: Are you finding your screenshots anywhere? Please post your MEDIA settings