# I couldn't play the audios that were uploaded to admin (the urls have quotation marks)

Tags: python, django, media-url

I created a new class in my model.py file:

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    .....
    audio_object = models.FileField(default='')
```

And I uploaded my audios to my admin page.
However, the audios don't play and I right-clicked to a new browser, it shows "Page Not Found" saying "The current path, *appname*/“/media/*nameoftheaudio*.mp3”, didn't match any of the URLconf defined in *projectname*.urls.

I reviewed the answers from [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root) but it didn't solve my problems. 
In my urls.py, I already have:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in my setting.py, I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Another piece of information is the audios I uploaded to another class work fine! And that is the first class model I created in this project. I can't detect what do I lack for this Audio class.
I am using Django 3.0.4
Thank you!!

Update: I think I found the issue: when I open the link for my audio, there are always quotation marks attached for "media/audio.mp3".
[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzrAQ.png)

How can I remove the quotation marks; I am pretty sure several days ago the media files work fine but ever since I added a new class it became like this. 
Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: how're you accessing the audio.Make sure that audio is uploaded and present inside `/media/`

Comment: @GaganSingh In the 404 page; it shows my current path is /media/audioname.mp3 but the listed URL patterns that Django found don't have /media/. I think the problem really should be the media_url in setting.py