# "GET /media/img/image.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2575

Tags: html, django, django-admin

When viewing page the image is not loaded. The image is uploaded via **Django-admin** The part of HTML template loading image is:

**Home.html**

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image.url }}">
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The error shown in the terminal:

> Not Found: /media/img/sandstone.png
> [00/Aug/0000 00:00:00] "GET /media/img/image.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2581

Comment: what is BASE_DIR?

Comment: You can get help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518073/6427186

Comment: Make sure you have `{% load static %}` at the top of your html page

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, django is not configured to serve user uploaded files. To serve them, add following to `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

However, please not that it is suitable only for local development, not for production. Relevant docs:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Thanks  Eugene, Adding the urlpatterns for MEDIA_ROOT worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the **urls.py** served the purpose:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```